# Parser returns either 'None' or '[]'

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

Here's the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b
URL = 'https://ege.sdamgia.ru/'
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = b(r.text, 'html.parser')
topics = soup.find_all(class_="Link-U Link_wrap-U Link_pseudo-U Link_pseudoBlack-U")
print(topics)
```

Please help guys

I want my parser to return topic titles from that site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, install selenium, because this site is dynamic.

  pip install selenium
- Download chrome or firefox driver (see google)

Examle using chromedriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from time import sleep

URL = 'https://ege.sdamgia.ru/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(URL)

#wait some time

sleep(5)

soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
topics = soup.find_all(class_="Link-U Link_wrap-U Link_pseudo-U Link_pseudoBlack-U")

print(topics)
```

Reading more about dynamic sites would be helpful.